# Python bank ATM

Tags: python

So I have a homework on coding a bank ATM machine and I have done most of the code but I do not seem to make work like the professor stated "If the user enters an invalid numeric value, inform the user as such. If the user enters a valid number between 0 and 100, display the amount of funds left in the account"

> example:
>
> `kitten : "Invalid Entry".`
>   `20.5 : "Your account has $79.50 remaining"`

My code so far:

```
amt = int(input("Withdraw amount: "))

if amt <= 0:
    print("Invalid Amount")
else:
    print{"Invalid Entry")

if amt > 100:
    print("Not enough funds in account")

if (amt >=0 and amt <=100):
    print("Your account has ${0:1.2f} remaining." .format(100-amt))
```

My issue is that when I enter `20.5` it give me an error

```
"ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '20.5'"
```

The second issue is when I enter a string `"ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'kitten'"`

Comment: change int() to float() around your input() func and try again.

Comment: `20.5` is not an integer value

Comment: Oh I forgot about float thanks now I just cant get the string to work when I enter string it gives this could not convert string to float: 'kitten'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why entering 20.5 gives you an error is because in the amt variable, it is looking for an integer to be inputted. In python, any number with a decimal is considered a float.

The code for the amt variable is currently

```
amt = int(input("Withdraw amount: "))
```

For the amt variable to have a number with a decimal as acceptable input, the amt variable should be this:

```
amt = float(input("Withdraw amount: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting everything to an int, so putting in strings and doubles will give you errors.  You need to check the content of your input before blindly converting it to an int.

You need to think about what your code is actually doing instead of just blindly changing things until they work without understanding why.